# aview: Invalid magic-not p?m family format

Tags: images, jpeg, xubuntu

I am simply trying to use `aview` to display a simple JPEG image using the terminal, however every time it returns this error:

```
Invalid magic-not p?m family format
```

It happens with other files of other formats too; I am not sure what the issue could be, and searching the error doesn't help much.

I am running Xubuntu 12.04 and using zsh as my shell.

Answer (score 6):

You could use *asciiview* command, from *man aview*:

> aview  can  only  show files in the PNM file format. But asciiview
>   automatically converts the file formats to PNM (with extern programs
>   like NetPBM and ImageMagic) and then runs aview.

So just use:

```
$ asciiview file.jpg
```

In case it doesn't work you might need to use:

```
$ sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

Comment: As it's the right answer to the question, I'll add a comment: if you want the same effect as `asciiview` without the need for `imagemagick` and have fun with colors too, switch to `caca-utils` package and its viewer tool: `cacaview`.

Answer (score 4):

**Option 1)** Convert it to pgm.

```
convert file.jpg file.pgm
```

Of course  convert must be installed.

Then:

```
aview file.pgm
```

---

**Option 2)** You can simply do:

```
asciiview file.jpg
```

Comment: Although this is a suitable workaround, this doesn't answer the question asked.

Comment: What question?  I don’t see a question. (I see a bunch of statements, including “I am not sure what the issue could be”, but no question.)